# Python: Reciveing 'none' when trying to add the string of an exception to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, error-handling, python-3.10

So I'm trying to get this working, where I remove the week's stats (weeklydict) from this second's stats (instantdict) so I have an accurate weekly progress for all keys of instantdict (keys being members). It works fine and dandy, but when a new member joins (adding to the keys in instantdict), shit hits the fan, so I use try/except, and attempt to add the missing member to weeklydict too, except when I do that using except keyerror as e and str(e), I'm given a 'none' value. Any idea on what to do?

Code:

```
for member, wins in instantDict.items():
try:
    instantDict[member] = instantDict[member] - weeklyDict[member]
except KeyError as e:
    weeklyDict[str(e)] = instantDict.get(str(e))    #error occurs here
    instantDict[member] = instantDict[member] - weeklyDict[member]  #thus fucking this up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my testing, `str(e)` returns a string as such:
`"'test'"`
The value is a string displaying a string, so `.get()` is not finding the value. Try something like:

```
for member, wins in instantDict.items():
    try:
        instantDict[member] = instantDict[member] - weeklyDict[member]
    except KeyError as e:
        weeklyDict[str(e).strip("'")] = instantDict.get(str(e).strip("'"))
        instantDict[member] = instantDict[member] - weeklyDict[member]
```

That should take the extra string characters off of the keyword, and allow `.get()` to actually find the value.

Alternatively, if you know that it errored because you know that `member` is not in the dictionary, why pull the exact same variable from the exception when you could just use `member` again?

Comment: Holy smokes it works dude! Thank you so much, greatly appreciated!

Comment: No prob! It's so weird that the exception returns it as a string of a string, but glad I figured it out for you!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it can't fetch the thing so try this:
weeklyDict[stre(e)] = instantDict.get(stre(e)]

Comment: Isn't this what OP had already had in their code? (With some weird modifications)

Comment: what do you mean with `stre(e)` ?